# flutter project build error when moved from one PC to other( window to mac)

Tags: gradle, flutter, dart

I move the flutter project from the window PC to Mac. I am facing this error I also try flutter clean but it did not work for. got an error by running flutter create.

```
    could not determine the dependencies of task app complieflutterbuilddebugarm flutter
java.net.URISytaxSException Illegal character in opaque part at index 2:c:\\User\\username\\Androidstudioprojects\\appname\\lib\\main.dart
```

when I make simple default project on window pc and move it to mac it works fine but my big project is not able to move.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/admin/Desktop/fluttersdk/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 875

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebugArm'.
> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\\Users\\Waqas\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Naija\\lib\\main.dart

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 45s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I got this after running flutter create

```
admin@mac-mini Naija 2 % flutter create
Warning! The 'flutter' tool you are currently running is from a different Flutter repository than the one last used by this package. The repository from which the 'flutter' tool is
currently executing will be used instead.
  running Flutter tool: /Users/admin/Desktop/flutter
  previous reference  : /Users/admin/Desktop/fluttersdk/flutter
This can happen when you have multiple copies of flutter installed. Please check your system path to verify that you are running the expected version (run 'flutter --version' to see
which flutter is on your path).


No option specified for the output directory.
Create a new Flutter project.

If run on a project that already exists, this will repair the project, recreating any files that are missing.

Usage: flutter create <output directory>
-h, --help                     Print this usage information.
    --[no-]pub                 Whether to run "flutter pub get" after the project has been created.
                               (defaults to on)

    --[no-]offline             When "flutter pub get" is run by the create command, this indicates whether to run it in offline mode or not. In offline mode, it will need to have all
                               dependencies already available in the pub cache to succeed.

    --[no-]with-driver-test    Also add a flutter_driver dependency and generate a sample 'flutter drive' test.
-t, --template=<type>          Specify the type of project to create.

          [app]                (default) Generate a Flutter application.
          [package]            Generate a shareable Flutter project containing modular Dart code.
          [plugin]             Generate a shareable Flutter project containing an API in Dart code with a platform-specific implementation for Android, for iOS code, or for both.

-s, --sample=<id>              Specifies the Flutter code sample to use as the main.dart for an application. Implies --template=app. The value should be the sample ID of the desired
                               sample from the API documentation website (http://docs.flutter.dev). An example can be found at
                               https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html

    --list-samples=<path>      Specifies a JSON output file for a listing of Flutter code samples that can created with --sample.
    --[no-]overwrite           When performing operations, overwrite existing files.
    --description              The description to use for your new Flutter project. This string ends up in the pubspec.yaml file.
                               (defaults to "A new Flutter project.")

    --org                      The organization responsible for your new Flutter project, in reverse domain name notation. This string is used in Java package names and as prefix in the
                               iOS bundle identifier.
                               (defaults to "com.example")

    --project-name             The project name for this new Flutter project. This must be a valid dart package name.
-i, --ios-language             [objc, swift (default)]
-a, --android-language         [java, kotlin (default)]
    --[no-]androidx            Generate a project using the AndroidX support libraries
```

Comment: did you clean your project?

Comment: yeah I did but it did not work for me.

Comment: Does "flutter --version" gives same response on both environment?

Answer (score 3):

don't  copy your .flutter-plugins file 
and make sure to run

```
flutter clean
```

and

```
flutter packages get
```

At last if not above mentioned worked, you try in the same project folder:

```
flutter create
```

Comment: I update the question look what I got after running flutter create

Comment: that's even worse, I recommend you to create a new project and transfer your codes

Comment: I have multiple projects to work on so transferring code will not be ok I need to have a solid solution to avoid such problems in future

Answer (score 3):

Remove `.packages` and execute `flutter pub get` in the command line.

Comment: thanks brother you don't your answer saved how much time for me actually i upgraded my pc from windows 7 to 10 so i migrated my project also but it was taking my older project path

Answer (score 0):

Faced same problem.

1. Simply open terminal
2. Run 'flutter clean',
   The error still shows
3. Now run 'flutter pub get'

if all this did not work, try upgrading your sdk by running
flutter upgrade